# Поймать нажатие кнопки Enter (Перейти) на мобильной клавиатуре Android

Tags: webkit, android, javascript, браузер

Вот этот код будет работать в обычных браузерах

```
      $("#moe_input_pole").keypress(function(e){
           if(e.keyCode==13){
           document.getElementById("route").click(); 
           }
         });
```

Но если сайт загрузить в мобильном браузере, и нажать кнопку Enter(Перейти) в всплывающей клавиатуре, там этот код не сработает,
Не сработает вот это строчка

```
document.getElementById("route").click();
```

Почему так?

Comment: На разных девайсах код Enter'а разный. Точно знаю, что разный на Samsung Galaxy S2 и Sony Xperia Go. Когда-то тестировал и нашёл это опытным путём.

Comment: Проверил, код кнопки выдает правильный "13", и сам скрип работает, не работает вставленная за место алерта строка 

document.getElementById("route").click();
Почему?

Comment: Очевидно проблема в браузере. [Народ говорит](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input), что похожая проблема наблюдается в Mozilla и Opera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замена проблемной строчки на, jquery код 
$('#route').click();
решило мою проблему. Ай да я ай да молодец))